# The choice of DB for a node.js server that needs to process lots of I/O?

Tags: database, node.js, webserver

What kind of DB should I use for a node.js server that needs to handle lots of concurrent DB accesses (at least more than 1000 concurrent requests to "update" entries, I assume), if there is one?

I was going to use MySQL with one DB connection per request but it looks like there may be a more suitable choice of DB for handling many DB connections (mostly updating entries as I mentioned it above with double quotes).

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend:

- MongoDB: if you have a lot of data should could possible spread over many servers
- Redis: faster then MongoDB, but harder if you hit the limit of having more data then one server could handle

They both have atomic update operations, which makes them a good choice for you. (This means you could update object without the need to fetching it before.)

They both different from what you maybe now from MySQL and you need to test which of them is more suitable for your data-structures.

A short comparision could be found here: http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis/

Best advice I could give you: Try out different technologies, benchmark them and then make a decision.

Comment: Having looked at both MongoDB and Redis, I'm contemplating using either MySQL or MongoDB since the durability of DB with approximately 200000 fixed entries is more important than the speed of updating them in my case. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you. Since this is your first question here on Stackoverflow I would like to remember you upvote answers that where helpfull and the make the one that gave to the solution as right, so future visitors of this question will have it more easy to decide what to do with their related problem.

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion would be to look at redis, depending on database structure and how much data you will be storing.

Answer (score 1):

I recommended a sharded MongoDB cluster. Mongoose is a package for Node that plays well with Mongo and is super easy to use.